# Removing "This program might not have installed correctly" warning from SFX

Tags: windows, executable, self-extracting

I am creating a self extracting executable, which is not an installer. It's a standalone exe, but it uses the app.config as a file based resource so I need to have it be a self extracting executable (Cannot avoid requirement that it must be one file that's double clickable). I would like those who download my exe to be able to run it without getting the "This program might not have installed correctly" message that pops up. I've added the manifest file with the correct settings to my project, but it seems that this did not do the trick. 
I've read that you can change the PE headers of the SFX file before you create the self extracting executable to fix the problem, but I'm not sure how I can actually do this (for free). I'm currently using 7zip's SFX file as a base, and I already edited the icon file and version info via Resource Hacker, but I'm lost on how to edit the PE headers.